# ошибка при запуске minecraft через bat

Tags: java, cmd, minecraft

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin\java.exe" -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Duser.language=en -Djava.library.path=D:/MultiMC/instances/1.17.1/natives -cp D:/MultiMC/jars/NewLaunch.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-glfw/3.2.2/lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-jemalloc/3.2.2/lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-openal/3.2.2/lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-opengl/3.2.2/lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-stb/3.2.2/lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl-tinyfd/3.2.2/lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/3.2.2/lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/blocklist/1.0.5/blocklist-1.0.5.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/patchy/2.1.6/patchy-2.1.6.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/github/oshi/oshi-core/5.7.5/oshi-core-5.7.5.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.8.0/jna-5.8.0.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.8.0/jna-platform-5.8.0.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.8.0-beta4/slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j18-impl/2.16.0/log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.16.0.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/66.1/icu4j-66.1.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/javabridge/1.1.23/javabridge-1.1.23.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.3/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/io/netty/netty-all/4.1.25.Final/netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/brigadier/1.0.18/brigadier-1.0.18.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/datafixerupper/4.0.26/datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/authlib/2.3.31/authlib-2.3.31.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/8.2.1/fastutil-8.2.1.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.16.0/log4j-api-2.16.0.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.16.0/log4j-core-2.16.0.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/text2speech/1.11.3/text2speech-1.11.3.jar;D:/MultiMC/libraries/com/mojang/minecraft/1.17.1/minecraft-1.17.1-client.jar org.multimc.EntryPoint

Launcher ABORT due to PARSE exception:
org.multimc.ParseException: Error while parsing:
        at org.multimc.EntryPoint.parseLine(EntryPoint.java:55)
        at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:106)
        at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)
Exiting with 1
```